# how to convert optional decimal type to String in swift

Tags: swift

I have one variable as optional decimal type and would like to convert into another `String` type variable if it is nil, change to empty string `""`, otherwise convert to string value. however I get the error
error: `Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Decimal?' and 'String'`

```
let iAmNil: Decimal? = nil
let iAmDecimal: Decimal? = 12.34
print(String(describing: iAmDecimal ?? ""))
```

Comment: Why not the most obvious `print(iAmDecimal?.formatted() ?? "")` rather than dealing with `Any`?

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, you're applying your `??` at the incorrect level. You're trying to provide a string default (`""`) to an optional Decimal. That doesn't work.

What you need is to conditionally convert the `Decimal?` to a `String?`, and then provide a default for *that*.

The easiest way is just using [`Optional.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/map(_:)):

```swift
import Foundation

let iAmNil: Decimal? = nil
let iAmDecimal: Decimal? = 12.34

print(iAmNil.map { String(describing: $0) } ?? "nil")
print(iAmDecimal.map { String(describing: $0) } ?? "nil")
```

(I used `"nil"` instead of `""` to show it's actually working in the output)

But of course, you should never use `String(describing:)` for formatting numbers to the user. Make sure you're using locale-aware tools like `NumberFormatter`, which will actually do it correctly.

Comment: so why `let iAmDecimal: Double? = 12.34 print(iAmDecimal ?? "")` works?

Comment: @jacobcan118 Because `print()` accepts `Any` as its first parameter.  This also works `let x: Any = iAmDecimal ?? ""` for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the conversion to `Any`, then that will work because the compiler is happy that either `Decimal` or `String` can used:

```
import Foundation

let iAmNil: Decimal? = nil
let iAmDecimal: Decimal? = 12.34
print(String(describing: (iAmDecimal ?? "") as Any))
// Prints 12.34\n
```